# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in FAL FileUpload using ext:form in TYPO3 10.4.0

Tags: typo3

I'm getting a PHP Exception "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" using a FAL FileUpload field in EXT:Form on clean TYPO3 10.4.0 (Composer Mode).

If FormState array contains an object of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference serialize not working in /public/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/ViewHelpers/FormViewHelper.php line 48

```
serialize(object(TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Runtime\FormState))
```

Is this a Bug ?

Comment: Does your Form definition contain more than one page ('step'), e.g. a summary page? I get the same error in this case.

Comment: Yes, I get this error calling the summary page. The error only occurred if a FAL Objected is submitted.

Comment: I added an issue on the TYPO3 Bugtracker: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91196

Comment: The issue was fixed in TYPO3 v10.4.5

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned behavior was a bug between TYPO3 version 10.4.0 and 10.4.4 - which has been addressed and fixed in TYPO3 version 10.4.5 with the following commit

```
[BUGFIX] Fix serialization of FileReference objects

FileReferences objects contain references to File
objects which itself contain service dependencies
(e.g. event dispatcher) which are not seralizable.

This leads to problems for instance when having
a multi-step form containing file uploads where
file reference objects are being serialized.
```

References:

- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91196
- https://review.typo3.org/q/I7650186adc5c61528e1a1adcf06b8d6cf67a55cd